# how to show retrived data from mysql table in sequential serial nos

Tags: php, mysql

i have to show the retrieved data from `MySQL` table using Php in orders like where the no should come link:

```
sln0   data1    data2

1      data     data

2      data     data 

3      data     data
```

but the serial nos should not the primary key auto increment id and one thing each data i have to show in each table definition.

Comment: couldn't get what you want exactly

Comment: You can use order by slin0 in your query

Answer (score 1):

You might be expecting this

```
SET @slno=0;
SELECT @slno:=@slno+1 AS slno, data1, date2 FROM your_table
```